# Read data from an excel file stored in memory

Tags: android

Hello My intention is to read data from certain cells of a file that I have in external memory of the mobile then put them to a few text fields and the user can modify them. I've imported the library jar apache POI and I don't do anything the application. In my code I get the path by checking the state of the external memory acquiring the path to the root directory and adding the name of the file. Then I create a procedure of reading data from the row and cell that will step in as parameters but does not react to this second part.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R. layout.user); findViewById(R. id.Btsalir).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { finish();
        }
    });
    final Button borra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnborra);
    if (estadisponible()) {
        String rutafinal = File.separator + "documents" + File.separator + "Siniestros.xlsx";
        obtenruta(rutafinal);
        try {
            leerdato(rutafinal,4,2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else {
        Toast to = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La memoria no esta disponible",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    };

}

public static boolean estadisponible(){
    String estado = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}
public  void obtenruta (String rutafinal ){
    File fichero = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File ruta = new File (fichero.getAbsolutePath(),rutafinal);
    Toast r = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ruta completa:" +ruta,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    r.show();

}

private void leerdato (String fichero, int fila, int celda) throws IOException {

    //instanciamos  el fichero pasado como argumento
    FileInputStream Fis = new FileInputStream(fichero);
    //instanciamos estructura de sistema de fichero
    POIFSFileSystem sistema = new POIFSFileSystem(Fis);
    //creamos un libro
    HSSFWorkbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook(sistema);
    //creamos hoja de un libro
    HSSFSheet hoja = libro.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow mifila = hoja.createRow(fila);
    HSSFCell micelda = mifila.getCell(celda);
    String dato = micelda.getStringCellValue();
    Toast toa = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "la celda contiene :" + dato, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toa.show();
}
}
```

Anyone can have any idea... I'm locked in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an IOException calling `leerdato(rutafinal,4,2)`. rutafinal is a relative path. In obtenruta() you add external storage directory. You should do that in leerdato() too. Look in the logcat for FileNotFoundException. Also add code in leerdato() (or before) to check if the file exists.